# Setting a variable for storing the user email without repeating the code in every function

Tags: php, codeigniter, credentials, ion-auth

I am using Ion_Auth library with Codeigniter 3.0.*. I managed to display the user email I am logged in with with this line of code in the `__construct()` method of my `Admin_Controller`:

```
$this->user_email = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
```

But I need to repeat this code:

```
$data['user_email'] = $this->user_email->email;
```

In every view method within every controller. I display the variable `$user_email` in my `header.php`, which is the same for every page. How do I make it accessible for everyone without repeating this line of code?

Comment: Is `header.php` a view?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class property `$data` to the Admin_controller class definition.
The $data property will be available to each controller that extends Admin_controller. Because it is a class property it is accessed with the syntax `$this->data`.

```
class Admin_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    //our new class property 
    protected $data = array(); 

    public function __construct(){
      parent :: __construct();
      // do what is needed to get $ion_auth working
    }
}
```

In any class extending `Admin_controller` set `$data['$user_email']` in the constructor. It is then available to every view that is given $this->data

```
class Some_controller extends  Admin_controller
{
    public function __construct(){
      parent :: __construct();
      //I am assuming that by this time $this->ion_auth->user() exists
      //so we add a key and value to the class' $data property 
      //Note the use of the "$this->" syntax)
      $this->data['user_email'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    }

    public function sets_up_a_view(){
       //do stuff until you're ready for the header
       //note that we are sending the class property "$this->data" to the view
       $this-load->view('header', $this->data);
       //load other views as needed using $this-data or other array - your choice
    }

    public function some_other_view(){
        //send class property to view
        $this-load->view('header', $this->data);
        $data['foo'] = 42;
        //send local var to view
        $this-load->view('other_parts', $data);
    }
}
```

Notice that both `sets_up_a_view()` and `some_other_view()` send the class property '$this->data' to `header.php`. But in `some_other_view()` we setup a local variable called `$data` to send to the `other_parts.php` view.

Comment: This is what I did. I call the `$data` variable in the `__construct()` method from my `Admin_controller`, which is extended by every other controller I have. The issue here is that I must repeat this `$data['user_email'] = $this->user_email->email;` within every method for calling my views. I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid repeating it, but I assume it does not?

Comment: @mfgabriel92, I have revised the answer to (I hope) make my solution more clear.

Comment: I found the solution! Check my own answer. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding these two lines of code in my `Admin_controller`:

```
$data['user_email'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->email;
$this->load->vars($data);
```

With this, every view method in the controllers extending `Admin_controller` can access this variable.